# How to delete AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEMRServerless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr-serverless

I am new to AWS and my account got hacked and in order to secure the account I have been advised to delete IAM roles. There is one role called `AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEMRServerless` that I am unable to delete as the error message says `Applications are in use`.

[image: Delete role]

Also I am unable to edit the policy linked the role. My AWS CLI also doesn't open (tried different browsers, regions and OSs). Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: [error](https://ibb.co/TL3S27Q)

Answer (score 1):

`AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEMRServerless` is a **service-linked role** created by AWS.

You can delete it, but your error message indicates that something is using the role, so it cannot be deleted. It is used by Amazon EMR, so you should check if your account is running any Amazon EMR Serverless services.

Frankly, there is no harm in leaving it there.

See: [Using service-linked roles - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, John. I carefully checked if there are running applications in all the regions of EMR. The issue is there has been unauthorized activity on my account and the AWS team won't adjust the billing unless I am able to delete the IAM role. Do you know of any other possibility? such as a policy/permission that can prevent the deletion of IAM roles?

Comment: It says "Applications are in use", so that is why it can't be deleted.